# Writing a list from a for loop into a csv

Tags: python, for-loop, export-to-csv, sentiment-analysis

I wrote a for loop that iterates through a CSV to get a list like this:

```
[t1, s1]
[t2, s2]
[t3, s3]
```

and so 4 thousand times. 
Now I need to write these into a new CSV file, where they'd populate 2 fields and be separated by a comma. 
When I enter this, I only get the last list from the last loop, and with one character in a cell.

```
def sentiment_analysis():
    fo = open("positive_words.txt", "r")
    positive_words = fo.readlines()
    fo.close()
    positive_words = map(lambda positive_words: positive_words.strip(), positive_words)
    fo = open("negative_words.txt", "r")
    negative_words = fo.readlines()
    fo.close()
    negative_words = map(lambda negative_words: negative_words.strip(), negative_words)
    fo = open("BAC.csv", "r")
    data = fo.readlines()
    fo.close()
    data = map(lambda data: data.strip(), data)
    x1 = 0 #number of bullish
    x2 = 0 #number of bearish
    x3 = 0 #number of unknown
    for info in data:
        data_specs = info.split(',')
        time_n_date = data_specs[0]
        sentiment = data_specs[2]
        '''Possibly precede with a nested for loop for data_specs???'''
        if sentiment == 'Bullish':
            '''fo.write(time + ',' + 'Bullish' + '\n')'''
        elif sentiment == 'Bearish':
            ''' fo.write(time + ',' + 'Bearish' + '\n')'''
        else:
            x3 += 1
            positive = 0
            negative = 0
            content_words = data_specs[1].split()
            for a in positive_words:
                for b in content_words:
                    if (a == b):
                        positive = positive + 1
            for c in negative_words:
                for d in content_words:
                    if (c == d):
                        negative = negative + 1
            if positive > negative:
                '''fo.write(time + ',' + 'Bullish' + '\n')'''
                sentiment = 'Bullish'
            elif positive < negative:
                sentiment = 'Bearish'
            else:
                sentiment = 'Neutral'
        bac2data = [time_n_date, sentiment]
        print bac2data
        fo = open("C:\Users\Siddhartha\Documents\INFS 772\Project\Answer\BAC2_answer.csv", "w")
        for x in bac2data:
            w = csv.writer(fo, delimiter = ',')
            w.writerows(x)
        fo.close()
```

My for loop isn't going through it all.

Comment: Can we see the code you are using to read in the data?

Comment: open in append mode, you are overwriting your file in each iteration

Comment: What @njzk2 said. I wrote my answer before OP included the script in its entirety.

Comment: @njzk2: while that will help, it's not a good solution to the problem. Simply changing the file to append mode will still require that the file be opened for every line of input and is very inefficient. Also, that's not the only problem - using `writerows()` on a string is also part of the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your code `bac2data = [time_n_date, sentiment]` creates a list containing 2 string items. The proper way to write that to a CSV file with `csv.writer()` is with `writerow(bac2data)`.

The last part of your code contains a number of errors. Firstly you are opening the CSV file in write mode (`'w'`) for every line of the incoming data. This will *overwrite* the file each time, losing all data except the last line. Then you are iterating over the `bac2data` list and calling `writerows()` on each item. That's going to write each character from the string on it's own line (which matches your reported output).

Instead, open the output file and create a `csv.writer` outside of the main `for info in data:` loop:

```
fo = open("C:\Users\Siddhartha\Documents\INFS 772\Project\Answer\BAC2_answer.csv", "w")
writer = csv.writer(fo)
for info in data:
    ....
```

Then replace these lines at the bottom of the main loop:

```
    bac2data = [time_n_date, sentiment]
    print bac2data
    fo = open("C:\Users\Siddhartha\Documents\INFS 772\Project\Answer\BAC2_answer.csv", "w")
    for x in bac2data:
        w = csv.writer(fo, delimiter = ',')
        w.writerows(x)
    fo.close()
```

with this:

```
    bac2data = [time_n_date, sentiment]
    print bac2data
    writer.writerow(bac2data)
```

Once you have that working, and no longer need to print `bac2data` for debugging, you can just use 1 line:

```
    writer.writerow((time_n_date, sentiment)]
```

---

**Update**

Complete code for function:

```
def sentiment_analysis():
    fo = open("positive_words.txt", "r")
    positive_words = fo.readlines()
    fo.close()
    positive_words = map(lambda positive_words: positive_words.strip(), positive_words)
    fo = open("negative_words.txt", "r")
    negative_words = fo.readlines()
    fo.close()
    negative_words = map(lambda negative_words: negative_words.strip(), negative_words)
    fo = open("BAC.csv", "r")
    data = fo.readlines()
    fo.close()
    data = map(lambda data: data.strip(), data)
    x1 = 0 #number of bullish
    x2 = 0 #number of bearish
    x3 = 0 #number of unknown

    fo = open("C:\Users\Siddhartha\Documents\INFS 772\Project\Answer\BAC2_answer.csv", "w")
    writer = csv.writer(fo)

    for info in data:
        data_specs = info.split(',')
        time_n_date = data_specs[0]
        sentiment = data_specs[2]
        '''Possibly precede with a nested for loop for data_specs???'''
        if sentiment == 'Bullish':
            '''fo.write(time + ',' + 'Bullish' + '\n')'''
        elif sentiment == 'Bearish':
            ''' fo.write(time + ',' + 'Bearish' + '\n')'''
        else:
            x3 += 1
            positive = 0
            negative = 0
            content_words = data_specs[1].split()
            for a in positive_words:
                for b in content_words:
                    if (a == b):
                        positive = positive + 1
            for c in negative_words:
                for d in content_words:
                    if (c == d):
                        negative = negative + 1
            if positive > negative:
                '''fo.write(time + ',' + 'Bullish' + '\n')'''
                sentiment = 'Bullish'
            elif positive < negative:
                sentiment = 'Bearish'
            else:
                sentiment = 'Neutral'

        bac2data = [time_n_date, sentiment]
        print bac2data
        writer.writerow(bac2data)

    fo.close()
```

Comment: So I have this. 
import modules
def sentiment_analysis():
fo = open("filepath", "w")
w = csv.writer(fo, delimiter = ',')
for info in data:
...
bac2data = time_n_date, sentiment
w.writerow(bac2data)
fo.close()
And I now get the list from last iteration on one line only. 
Thanks!

Comment: @squidvision: What's in your data? Is there more than 1 line? I can't tell from the code in the comment the levels of indentation. I've updated my answer with the full solution based on the code that you posted.